# Consulta getJSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta aJax usando getJSON, mas não retorna o valor. O que estou fazendo de errado?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ver").click(function() {

        nome=$("#course").attr("value");

        $.getJSON("teste3.php", {cpf_cnpj:nome}, function(json){
            $("#cpf_cnpj").html(json[0].cpf_cnpj);
            $("#rsocial").html(json[0].cnh);

        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>


    <strong>Cliente:</strong> 
    <input type="text" name="cliente" id="course" value="00.000.000/0000-00" size="40" /> 
    <input type="button" value="ver" id="ver" />

    <p>

    <input type="text" id="cpf_cnpj" name="cpf_cnpj" value="">
    <input type="text" id="rsocial" name="rsocial" value="">



</body>
</html>
```

Arquivo teste3.php

```
<?php

    $conexao = mysql_connect('localhost', '', '') or die  ("Erro na conexão ao banco de dados.");
    mysql_select_db('',$conexao) or die ("Erro ao selecionar a base de dados.");



    $selec = "SELECT ID_Cliente, cpf_cnpj, rsocial FROM clientes WHERE cpf_cnpj = '".$_GET["cpf_cnpj"]."' ";
    $exec = mysql_query($selec, $conexao) or die(mysql_error());

    while($campos=mysql_fetch_array($exec)) {
        extract($campos);
        $Array = Array();

        $Array[] = Array("ID_Cliente" => "$ID_Cliente", "cpf_cnpj" => "$cpf_cnpj", "rsocial" => "$rsocial");

        $json_encode = json_encode($Array);
        echo $json_encode;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Você reparou que o nome do arquivo para consulta está `"teste3.php"`?

Comment: @RodrigoSpeller, sim eu coloquei errado no post.

Comment: Quando eu faço a consulta direto no navegador aparece o resultado. **teste3.php?cpf_cnpj=00.000.000/0000-00** `[{"ID_Cliente":"1","cpf_cnpj":"00.000.000\/0000-00","rsocial":"Teste ME"}]`

Comment: Parece tudo certo. Dá algum erro no console do browser?

Comment: Estranho, não esta sendo enviado o VALUE, veja imagem http://i.imgur.com/bzLtPTt.png

Comment: Mudei de `nome=$("#course").attr("value");` para `nome=$('#course').val();` e agora esta passando o valor, mas não ainda não retorna o valor da busca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Arquivo teste2.php:**

Substitua:

```
nome=$("#course").attr("value");
```

por:

```
nome=$("#course").val();
```

Substitua também:

```
$("#cpf_cnpj").html(json[0].cpf_cnpj);
$("#rsocial").html(json[0].cnh);
```

por:

```
$("#cpf_cnpj").val(json[0].cpf_cnpj);
$("#rsocial").val(json[0].rsocial);
```

**Arquivo teste3.php:**

Creio que há problema com os conjuntos de caracteres.

Coloque na primeira linha de código:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```

e depois da conexão coloque essa linha

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

De preferência, sempre use UTF-8.

Não esqueça de salvar os arquivos no formato UTF-8 sem BOM.

Comment: Olá Rodrigo, fiz como falou e mesmo assim não funcionou. No Arquivo teste2.php voloquei o `<?php header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"); ?>`, mas ao inves de aparecer o form aparece o código

Comment: No meu funcionou, vou refazer aqui do zero e ver o que está diferente.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Você alterou o nome do arquivo Teste?

Comment: Continua o mesmo. TESTE2.PHP é o que tem o form html. TESTE3.PHP é o que busca no banco de dados.

Comment: Manda um DUMP do banco se não for muito grande.

Comment: Você vai colocar `header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8")` no arquivo *teste3.php*.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23678/discussion-between-tiago-and-rodrigo-speller).

Comment: Estou no chat, coloquei o BD la